# JQuery vs Angular implementation of hundreds of value sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

My question is about how to approach performance on a page with hundreds of dynamic JS elements.

I have a page that will load 700 food items. Each food item has a select box where the measure (eg loaf vs slice of bread) may be chosen, a value-slider, and an output showing the value selected * the weight of the measurement. Each item also has a "favourite" checkbox. If this is checked, the item will be copied into a "Favourites" list. The value inputs of items in the "Favourites" list  are "mirrored" in the original food item below, so that if a "Favourite" slider is moved, the slider of original item will be moved simultaneously.

Here's a text sketch of what I mean:

```
//Favourites
(*) Bread (slice/loaf) (slider) [output]

//Food items
(*) Bread (slice/loaf) (slider) [output]
() Potatoes (mashed/boiled/fries) (slider) [output]
```

I've implemented all of this with JQueryUI sliders & some assorted JQuery to watch for the values of the select boxes & checkboxes. Unsurprisingly, once 700 of these things are loaded, the DOM is dead as a doornail. I need a better solution.

Is it likely that implementing all of this behaviour in AngularJS instead would improve performance?

Comment: use input type=range, it has no extra impact on performance compared to text boxes. you can fall-back to what you have now for older browsers...

Comment: displaying 700 items at a time to user doesn't sound very user friendly. Another thing might consider is only use one slider and have it get it's values changed when user hovers item parent. `slider on demand` so to speak

Comment: Any change you do could potentially affect performance. That's a silly question to ask. Figure out where the slowdown is happening exactly, it's likely that you are using very inefficient selectors or events. I angularjs can do it efficiently, so can jquery. they're both just javascript.

Comment: Agree that 700x anything on one page is a UX mess, and am trying to reduce that. However, it's still going to be a large number- e.g 40-60. I'm very interested in ways to optimise efficiency of selectors and events over large numbers of DOM elements, if you have any suggestions or resources.

Comment: @Ali AngularJs is definitely your friend for two reasons: It keeps your code smaller and therefore more easily understood/maintained, and you don't worry with selectors. Instead, you write Angular directives that will create/attach behavior to the elements. It's simple and intuitive. Something like: `<div ng-repeat="food in foods"><div myFoodDirective="food"></div></div>`. Of course, this is just an example, but then you would just write a food directive to determine how the item should be handled, passing in the object `food` from the `$scope.foods` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't sound like a very good idea to have 700 of anything on one page...that's probably a terrible mess for whoever uses it. So, first, I recommend rethinking that plan altogether. That said, on my slow and outdated laptop, [this angular example (click)](http://jsbin.com/EZUtugu/2/edit) ran reasonably well. It has 700 inputs that are ALL changing their values every second. While I don't recommend it, I think it could be done as long as you keep everything efficient. Furthering that thought, the real inefficiency is having 700 items on the page to begin with. Loading the items as needed (on scroll, pagination, search, etc) makes a lot more sense and is the common solution.